# Is there any way to ignore ALL certificate-related issues in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificate, selenium, mitmproxy

I know there is a similar question, but my issue is a bit different. I am trying to implement what is basically a MITM "attack". Using quotation marks, because it's not an attack, rather, I am attempting to capture traffic while accessing a site via Selenium. 
The error I am getting is `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR` in Firefox. I don't see any warning about an invalid certificate, only this one.

Is there any way around it?